# How to take Multiple photo using Cordova Camera Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, camera, phonegap-build

I have been testing on Android and my goal is to take multiple photos, using either Cordova Camera or Media Capture, and save them to a gallery that will automatically correct/fix orientation. The back button in conjunction with the Media Capture, cancels the photo taking session, but seems to save the photos without corrected orientation. If I take photos using Camera plugin I get exactly what I need but I can only take one photo at a time.  Is there a way to wrap navigator.camera.getPicture into a loop that will take a photo until the cancel/back button is applied. It seems that the function is asynchronous and I haven't been able to get it to work no matter the approach.

What's strange is if I use the File manager to manually copy the files saved by media capture plugin into the gallery or the same folder the orientation is corrected.

UPDATE: I solved it by calling a function to take a picture again in the success event.

```
function takePicture(){

navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        correctOrientation: true,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    }); 

}

function cameraSuccess(uri){   
    //alert(uri);
    takePicture();    
}

function cameraError(message){
    alert("Canceled!"); 
}

$('#ThumbnailTest_buttonTakePhotosNow').click(function(){
    takePicture();
});
```

Comment: try this plugins 

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.synconset.imagepicker

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.synconset.imagepickerex

Answer (score 1):

OP Mentioned solution in Question so I think better to add as Answer:

You can do this by calling a function to take a picture again in the success event.

```
function takePicture(){

navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        correctOrientation: true,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    }); 

}

function cameraSuccess(uri){   
    //alert(uri);
    takePicture();    
}

function cameraError(message){
    alert("Canceled!"); 
}

$('#ThumbnailTest_buttonTakePhotosNow').click(function(){
    takePicture();
});
```